# Redshift FULL OUTER JOIN doesn't output NULL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We have a 'numbers' table that holds 0-10000 values in its single value 'n'.
We have tableX that has calculated_at datetime and a term.
We are trying to fill the holes where in tableX doesnt have matches in the given dates. HOWEVER, this doesn't seem to yield NULL or 0 for the non-matching...

```
select term
     , avg(total::float)
     , date_trunc('day', series.date) as date1
     , date_trunc('day', calculated_at) as date2
from (select 
        (current_timestamp - interval '1 day' * numbers.n)::date as date
      from numbers) as series
full outer join terms
   on series.date = date_trunc('day', calculated_at)
where series.date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30'
AND (term in ('term111') or term is null)
group by term
       , date_trunc('day', series.date)
       , date_trunc('day', calculated_at)
 order by date_trunc('day', series.date) asc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `full outer join` is fine.  The problem is the filters.  These are really tricky with a `full outer join`.  I would recommend:

```
select t.term, avg(total::float),
       date_trunc('day', series.date) as date1,
       date_trunc('day', calculated_at) as date2
from (select (current_timestamp - interval '1 day' * numbers.n)::date as date
      from numbers
      where (current_timestamp - interval '1 day' * numbers.n)::date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30'
     ) series full outer join
     (select t.*
      from terms
      where term = 'term111'
     ) t
     on series.date = date_trunc('day', t.calculated_at)
group by t.term, date_trunc('day', series.date), date_trunc('day', calculated_at)
 order by date_trunc('day', series.date) asc;
```

My guess though is that a `left join` would do what you want.  I doubt a `full outer join` is what you really intend.  If you have doubts, ask *another* question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Perfect! outer join yields ERROR:  could not devise a query plan for the given query. so I switched as your recommendation to the LEFT